# meaning of goró in Portuguese, is it a slang for alcohol?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, vocabulário

What does it mean "goró"? It is word from Portuguese.

hypothesis: is it a slang for alcohol

And what is its grammatical gender?

Thank you.

Comment: Brazilian Portuguese?

Comment: Can you add to the question a sample sentence or two?

Comment: I've never heard that word before.

Comment: Brazilian Portuguese, yes, sentence: ''tomar uns goró''

Comment: @cornejo http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/gor%F3/

Comment: A "goró" is any alcoholic beverage.

Comment: @Centaurus You've never heard it? Maybe it could be that it's more commonly heard in São Paulo? I don't know what other regions also use it.

Comment: @BrunoLopes   Yes, Bruno, I never heard it.  I asked the members of my family about it and they haven't heard it either.  "tomar uns goró" with "goró" in the singular form, sounds like "linguagem de funkeiros" to me, do tipo "nóis fexa nessa".

Comment: @Centaurus, I heard that term also here in RS State. It's not common. About the "funkeiros", I just discovered it is used in music like [this one](https://m.vagalume.com.br/wesley-safadao/secar-tudo.html)!

Comment: @gmauch   Guess I wasn't wrong about it.  We have to stress that it's unusual because we have members here who are learning Portuguese as a second language, and If one of them ever comes to Brazil and starts using unusual slang or regionalisms, they may become a laughing stock.

Comment: @Centaurus, perfect! It should be clear that the usage of this term is very informal and perhaps restricted to some regions and people using it might hear a lot of "what???"

Answer (score 5):

In Brazilian Portuguese, "goró" is a slang word used to refer to alcoholic beverages (usually vodka, whisky, beer, etc.), but can also mean specifically the "[cachaça](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacha%C3%A7a)". It's gender is masculine, so if you want to say that you will have a drink, it could be said as:

> Vou tomar um goró.

Or in the plural:

> Vou tomar uns gorós.

It's not so common, but sometimes you still hear someone say this slang, although it's not at every region in Brazil that people will know what "goró" means.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answers, *goró* is a male gender word, but I wouldn't say that it is exactly a slang for alcoholic beverages.

It's more an informal term used when someone intends to drink a lot and not specifically one kind of beverage. For instance, if you're going do drink a bottle of wine, you wouldn't "let's have a *goró*", it's more used when you are, let's say, going to a party and you intend to drink as much as you can, then you can say "let's have a *goró*!"

BTW, it's used in this sense in some musics, like [this one](https://m.vagalume.com.br/wesley-safadao/secar-tudo.html).

Comment: Like "encher a cara" or "bebedeira", right? It can also have this meaning, but there's some contexts, for example "chapar de goró" or "encher a cara de goró", that makes more sense if "goró" is a beverage, wouldn't?

Comment: "vou ali tomar um goró" pode ser dito quando alguém vai se dirigir a um lugar que vende ou tenha bebidas alcoólicas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a slang for alcoholic drink, and it's used in male gender.

"Eu tomei um goró"